# Writing tests for a pricing method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I am new to unit testing/TDD and having problem getting my head certain aspects of it. For example I am not sure how complete the tests should be imagine the following scenario.

I am writing a test to ensure I get the correct prices for a product. A product can come in different sizes and bought in a number of defined quantities. The price of the product will reflect the size and quantity.

For example:

Product A has the pricing matrix below (quantity down the side and size along the top)

```
----------------------------
|     | xs |  s |  m |  l  | 
----------------------------
|  250| 10 | 20 | 50 | 100 | 
----------------------------
|  500| 20 | 40 | 60 | 110 | 
----------------------------
| 1000| 15 | 25 | 55 | 105 | 
----------------------------
| 1500| 12 | 22 | 52 | 102 | 
----------------------------
```

Now say I was writing tests for a class method

```
Pricer.GetPrice(Product p, string size, int quantity)
```

Should I test for every product/size/quantity combo? as you can imagine this could mean a large number of tests.

If the prices are sourced from a data store and thus liable to change how do you keep your tests correct or is that just a annoying by product?

Also does anyone have any good links to read regarding writing tests/TDD. Maybe going through CRUD/Repositories as this seems a bit of a chicken and egg type scenario.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-Kent-Beck/dp/0321146530/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325797578&sr=1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there are two elements to your pricing logic.

1. A price matrix data structure mapping (size, quantity cutoff) pairs to prices.
2. A function that takes a price matrix and a `Product` instance and returns a price.

Testing the price matrix is meaningless; the numbers are arbitrary.  If you feel you need to test the function, I would pass it different fake, hard-coded test matrices with different mock products and test to verify that the right price comes out.  The most relevant edge cases are probably when you ask for a price for a cutoff quantity exactly or off-by-one from one.

Comment: Will accept this as the answer although all answers have helped my train of thought thanks very much all.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is about testing the smallest possible unit of code, so in this case all you care about is that the method returns the expected price. If the method is getting pricing data externally, then it's doing two things: getting pricing data and calculating a price. You've identified a breach of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Split it into two methods: one to *get pricing data*, and one to *calculate prices* (using pricing data passed as a parameter).

So your target method now looks like:

```
GetPrice(Product p, string size, int quantity, sometype pricingData)
```

Now you can test the calculation in isolation:

```
var pricingData = GetKnownPricingData(); // get a set of dummy pricing data
var result = Pricer.GetPrice(product, size, quantity, pricingData);
```

Then you can check for the expected result based on the known pricing data.

Comment: Thanks Igby helped clarify my thoughts.

Comment: You want to separate concerns as much as you can without reaching the point of diminishing returns. It's possible to over-apply principles of good design to the point that you end up complicating the architecture and erasing the benefit you seek. If it feels neater and not overly obscure to inject the pricing data from outside the pricer, do it. It's certainly a common design pattern. But always weigh the benefit against the cost, and keep [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think your testing needs to be specific, and you need to determine what you are testing before you start writing test.

Consider adding two numbers? You don't have to test every given combination of 2 numbers to add.  You write a test and give it 2 numbers and check that the returned value is indeed the sum of those numbers.

You asked about testing each size/quantity combination.  If there isn't a defined calculation for determining this, and you have variable values used for calculation, you can't really test for that.

You can test this: Size of X and Quantity of Y should give Price of Z.  Plug in the values for X and Y and ensure you get the expected value for Z.

What if there is no value for X or Y? Do you fail? Return 0?  These things you can test for.

Answer (score 0):

In real life you will normally stub you database, so it will return know objects, independent of the storage. If you are using eg. NUnit framework for testing, you can aslo decorate your tests with `TestCaseAttribute` to run a test with many different parameters and return values.